# which IDE should I use for aosp android?

Tags: android, ide, android-source

I need to customize SystemUI based on 6 to 9 but problem is when I am comparing the 6 source code patch to apply in 9, there are possibilities of missing import statement and method mapping
when I import the entire aosp project and do. But when I import the entire aosp project, it will not display compile error of System UI methods to import or missing class.

May I know which is the best IDE to use for aosp system apps?

Answer (score 5):

There is a tool called idegen to generate project files for IntelliJ and Eclipse.  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/refs/heads/master/tools/idegen/README

```
If you're using IntelliJ...
    If this is your first time using IDEGen...
        Android is large, thus IDEA needs a lot of memory. Add "-Xms1g -Xmx5g" to
        your VM options in "Help > Edit Custom VM" and increase the
        file size limit in "Help -> Edit custom properties" by adding
        "idea.max.intellisense.filesize=100000". Make sure to restart the IDE for
        the new settings to take effect.
        Create a JDK configuration named "1.8 (No Libraries)" by adding a new
        JDK like you normally would and then removing all of the jar entries
        under the "Classpath" tab. This will ensure that you only get access to
        Android's core libraries and not those from your desktop VM.
    From the project's root directory...
        Repeat these steps after each sync...
        1) make (to produce generated .java source)
        2) development/tools/idegen/idegen.sh
        3) Open android.ipr in IntelliJ. If you already have the project open,
           hit the sync button in IntelliJ, and it will automatically detect the
           updated configuration.
        If you get unexpected compilation errors from IntelliJ, try running
        "Build -> Rebuild Project". Sometimes IntelliJ gets confused after the
        project changes significantly.
```

Note that some tweaks should be done in IntelliJ project for optimal performance https://web.archive.org/web/20220111212957/http://effie.io/opening-aosp-with-intellij-part-3/.

IntelliJ is very very good when modifying framework Java parts and very terrible if you need to change C / C++. For that I use VS code (I load just the module I need like Hwcomposer or tinyalsa HAL)

Comment: effie.io link is dead.

Comment: @Maxwell175 Replaced the dead link with archived copy :)

Answer (score 1):

There is an Android Studio version released for platform (AOSP) developers. You can find more info here :
https://developer.android.com/studio/platform

AFAIK it only works on Linux.

Answer (score -4):

To develop aosp system apps, you should use Code Editing tool like Visual Code then build by AOSP build system (using makefile)